# Shell script: grep a table of values from a file

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk

I have a result file that looks like this:

```
data data data data data...
data data data data data...
data data data data data...

#0
data data is 2

#1
data data is 2

testing data (  )

   n         m  
  256      729.44      
  352     1555.07      
  448     2649.68      

#2
data data is 2

#3
data data is 2
```

I need to grep only the table that will always have 2 columns of n and m(it can get very long). So the output should be:

```
    n         m  
  256      729.44      
  352     1555.07      
  448     2649.68
```

I've tried using awk and grep but I can only get one line not the whole table. Any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: If one of the answer below solved your problem, please consider marking one of them correct by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that best solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no empty lines in the table, then one can use gawk like this:

```
awk '$1 == "n" && $2 == "m"' RS=
```

It will print the block which start with `n`, and `m` in the two first fields.

Comment: could you please explain how to use RS here? I looked it up but not really understanding how to use it.  Thank you

Comment: @Samy This might describe it for you ;) `man awk | awk '$1 == "RS"' RS=`

Comment: oh I see. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK you would print all lines where the Number of Fields equals to 2:

```
awk 'NF == 2' data.txt
```

Comment: Nice! I've always used the `{ print $0 }`, awk always surprising me. Thank you @andlrc